# Difference between data flow and control flow

Tags: data-flow-analysis, access-control

I am trying to read a paper. I can’t understand the difference between data flow and control. Maybe control flow means OS's or hardware's steps taken for execution of statements whereas data flow stands for passage of data as a result of execution of statements. Link of paper is

https://www.usenix.org/system/files/osdi18-cui.pdf, named 
REPT: Reverse Debugging of Failures in Deployed Software

I have problem with following:

> REPT reconstructs the execution history with high fidelity by
>   combining online lightweight hardware tracing of a program’s control
>   flow with offline binary analysis that recovers its data flow.

Kindly explain me the difference between dataflow and control flow.

Zulfi.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_flow

Comment: If you got the answer can you please post it. I am also confused